# Responsive design and clearfix

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design, clearfix

I have this responsive layout for a page. The `<aside>` is with constant width and the `.main` area has a `margin-right`. I do this because I want the `.main` area to adapt to different devices, while the `<aside>` remains constant.

http://jsfiddle.net/c6mZN/1/

The problem, as you can see, is that I have inside the main area a list of object that also use the clearfix, and the first element clears the object all the way until the end of the sidebar. What I want is that it looks exactly like the rest of `.block`

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forked your fiddle with fixed code.](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/3SEv8/)

Your `.main` element needs to know it has a separate 'formatting context', such that its children can ignore the external layout flow: the only way to do this in standards-compliant browsers is with `overflow: hidden`:

```
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Incidentally, you can then get rid of the margin on `.main` and it will automatically occupy whatever space is left (so you can then change the width of `aside` as you see fit, or even add extra columns) — I then gave the `aside` `margin-left: 10px` to dictate the gap it needs to keep your layout constant.